# SwiftUI - How do I change the text color of a Textfield?

Tags: swift, colors, textcolor, swiftui

I'm trying to change the textcolor of Textfield (the text that user write) in SwiftUI. I'm trying with foregroundColor but it changes the placeholder's text color.

How do you do this in SwiftUI?

```
 TextField($variable, placeholder: Text("a text"))
            .foregroundColor(.green)
```

Comment: This issue was fixed with Xcode 11 beta 3.

Comment: But now how do I change the placeholder color? Lol

Answer (score 48, accepted):

`.foregroundColor` actually does change the text color of `TextField` but only when it has a default value, for example this will work fine:

```
TextField(.constant("Hello World"), placeholder: Text("Type here..."))
  .foregroundColor(.green)
```

But once you **remove the whole text**, text field loses not only its color but the rest of its modifiers such as its alignment as well. This is likely a bug in the current version so I'll file a bug report.

---

**Update**: This issue was fixed with **Xcode 11 beta 3**.

Comment: Since the official release of Xcode 11 (or possibly earlier), it no longer seems to be possible to have a `Text` placeholder).

Answer (score 7):

Use `background()` to set background color and `foreground()` to set input text color

```
struct PlaygroundTestView: View {
    
    @State var searchText = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        
        TextField("Search", text: $searchText)
        .font(Font.system(size: 14))
        .padding()
        .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 50).fill(Color.white))
        
        .foregroundColor(.black)
        .padding()
        .offset(x:8, y: 10)
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this now broken / nonworking in Xcode 12 / iOS14?  I have tried setting the foreground color, background color, and .bold as described here and all I get is a faint gray mostly non-readable text.

Comment: "faint gray mostly non-readable text" is the placeholder text. The input text is set at black. This works for Catalina/xcode 12.

Answer (score 2):

Text color should be changed for using the Property of text field `.foreground color` 
Updated for `Xcode Version 11.1 (11A1027)`

> SwiftUI

```
TextField("Email", text: $email)
                .textContentType(.emailAddress)
                .padding(.init(top: 0, leading: 15, bottom:0 , trailing: 15))
                .foregroundColor(.blue)
                .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle.init())
```

Answer (score -1):

**If You want to give specific color your text in swift 5**

```
Text("Your Text")
     .foregroundColor(Color(uiColor: UIColor(red: 0.631, green: 0.678, blue: 0.769, alpha: 1)))
```

Comment: This has already been mentioned in the other answers.

Comment: which one is show Color with RGB ? @EricAya

Comment: The solution is `.foregroundColor` which was already given. Whether you use SwiftUI's Color or UIKit's UIColor inside is irrelevant.